# Re-write rules for AJAX Crawling

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

To redirect `mysite.com/category1` URL, the following rule works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^category1([^?]*) index.php?route=category&path=1 [L,NC]
```

For AJAX crawling, I need to use #! hash fragment. So, new URL will become `mysite.com/category1#!`. However, #! is converted to _escaped_fragment_ automatically by Google.

So, for crawling, Google fetches my server using the following URL:

```
mysite.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=category1
```

The following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^escaped_fragment_=(category1)$ 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?route=category&path=1&%1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

redirects from the above Google fetched URL to the following URL successfully first time:

```
mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_=category1
```

Then again, unwanted loop redirects to:

```
mysite.com/category1
```

Simply, I need re-write rules to redirect from:

```
mysite.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=category1
```

to:

```
mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_=category1
```

Please help me what rules I should write.

Comment: Unfortunately URL fragment after `#` is not seen by web server. So when your AJAX url is `mysite.com/category1#!` Apache will get only `mysite.com/category1` so you cant match it. Better to do this in your Javascript itself.

Comment: I don't want to view mysite.com/category1#! on browser. My sitemap submits this URL to Google. And then, Google converts it to mysite.com/category1_escaped_fragment_  and their bot access to my Apache server using this modified URL. So, web server doesn't need to process #!, instead it needs to process _escaped_fragment_.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: oh ok so server gets: `/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_` URI? If yes then where should this be rewritten to?

Comment: Please note that if I fetch mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1#! by Google webmaster tool, my web server gets mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_ for that request successfully. But, I need to fetch its permanent URL mysite.com/category1#! by Google webmaster tool.

Comment: ok which is good but what should rule do with `mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_` URL?

Comment: Currently, rule is: RewriteRule ^((category1)([^?]*)) index.php?route=category&path=1 [L,NC]

Comment: yes that i know but what should this new rule do (in words)?

Comment: I am not sure. I think it wouldn't need more rule for this reason. But, when I fetch via mysite.com/category1#!, it doesn't get $_GET[_escaped_fragment_]. Should I modify any existing rule?

Comment: `_escaped_fragment_` is empty parameter so `$_GET['_escaped_fragment_']` will also be empty. I am now confused what the requirement is.

Comment: It is required to convert from mysite.com/category1&_escaped_fragment_ to mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?route=category&path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, my last comments behind the question was wrong. Actually, it needs to convert from "mysite.com/category1?_escaped_fragment_=" to "to mysite.com/index.php?route=category&path=1&_escaped_fragment_" URL. How can I do this?

Comment: No, this rule didn't work for me. I've tried differently. The following rule redirect to expected url initially,                                   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(_escaped_fragment_=)(category1)$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?route=category&path=1&%1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
                                                                   But, it redirects to the permanent url: "mysite.com/category1" and so forth it generates AJAX page. If it comes with _escaped_fragment_, it should not redirect to AJAX page.

Comment: It is really confusing and unclear what do you really want. Can you edit your question and clearly explain your source URL and your expected rewrite.

Comment: Thank you for long discussion to solve my issue, though I handled this issue unwisely. According to your suggestion, I edited the question. Surprisingly, edited question somehow illustrates my possible answer for the original question. I puzzled because of redirection. This permanent redirect code was written in another php file.